# Getting Location of friends from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get home town location and current location of all my friends by my application. I came to know that for getting location I have to set permissions and write FQL. I wrote that and the URL became as
[My Graph API format](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name,%20uid,%20current_location,%20hometown_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20in%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29)
but when I use this link to get json I am not getting the values. I tried replacing %20 by space and tried that even but that too dint worked.
Please tell me what went wrong. and tell me what URL should I use.

My code to get json values..:

```
String q = "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT name, uid, current_location, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
              HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(q);
              try {
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();
                    if (httpEntity != null){
                        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String stringReadLine = null;

                        while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                         stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                         }

                        qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
                        inputStream.close();
                       }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              try {
                 Log.e("in try block", "in try block");
                JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(qResult);
                JSONArray JsonArray = JsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i = 0;i < JsonArray.length(); i++){
                    Log.e("jksdhkvjsdlvm", "inside 1st for loop");
                    JSONObject fbInfo = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = fbInfo.getString("name");
                    uid = fbInfo.getString("uid");
                    current_location = JsonObject.getJSONArray("current_location");
                    for(int j = 0;j < current_location.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject currentInfo = current_location.getJSONObject(j);
                        c_city = currentInfo.getString("city");
                        c_state = currentInfo.getString("state");
                        c_country = currentInfo.getString("country");
                        Log.e("--->>>>", c_city);
                    }
                    hometown_location = JsonObject.getJSONArray("hometown_location");
                    for(int k = 0;k < hometown_location.length(); k++){
                        JSONObject homeInfo = hometown_location.getJSONObject(k);
                        h_city = homeInfo.getString("city");
                        h_state = homeInfo.getString("state");
                        h_country = homeInfo.getString("country");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Encode the string and use it you will get response as there are special characters and dont manually put %20 instead of space encode it

Comment: the url was already in encoded form.. But i cant get the information.. I tried using both encoded format as well as decoded format of url..

Comment: @Vaibs: Can you post the code where you run this FQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do it simpler thru Graph API.

1) you need access_token with permissions;

```
To read Posts with location information, you need:
    user_photos or friends_photos for Photos
    user_status or friends_status for Posts (not including Photos)
    user_checkins or friends_checkins for Checkins only (excluding all other types of Posts)
```

2) then call this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=
```

this will return location_tagged items of Me (authenticated user) + Friends

Comment: Ya i did that but its specifically coming for likes and all.. its not mentioning Location(current , Hometown) for every friends.. and this is different form the link which i have mentioned in my question..

Comment: you are right! hometown type info is part of user profile. the example I gave in answer will get you 'user initiated location items (checkin, tag, ...)'.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried replacing %20 by space and tried that even but that too dint worked.

URL-encoding a value is about more then just replacing spaces. There’s other characters, that want to be replaced by their %xy representation as well – for example the commata.

URL-encode the *whole* FQL query in a correct way, and it will work:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT+name%2C+uid%2C+current_location%2C+hometown_location+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+in+%28SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+%3D+me%28%29%29